# What are these swirly green growths inside my bell peppers?

Tags: vegetables, identification, peppers

I occasionally discover swirly green growths inside my bell peppers, such as the ones pictured below.  What are they exactly?  Are they edible?

[image: bell pepper growths]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an internal proliferation known as a form of parthenocarpy - formation of fruit without fertilization. So it's just a sort of clone or internal baby pepper, sometimes looking much more like a pepper than the pic you've shown. Common in sweet peppers and yes, edible.